# How to negative match regex in JavaScript string replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to replace with a blank all characters except numbers, but this doesn't works:

`s.replace(/(?!\d)/g, '')`

Thanks!

Comment: `/[^\d]/g` http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use negative character classes:

`s.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')`

or `s.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '')`

or `s.replace(/\D+/g, '')`